# Is there any way to play video other then .mp4 on Android in Kivy?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, kivy

While I didn't find this in docs, currently only way to play video on Android in Kivy is to use [ffmpeg](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/ffmpeg). Am I right?

Even so looks like default ffmpeg recipe [supports](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2649#issuecomment-64537795) only `.mp4` videos. Is there any way to make it work with `.avi` and other popular video formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After merging [this PR](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/954) to p4a it'll be possible to specify `ffpyplayer_codecs` recipe to install codecs for `ffpyplayer` video provider. `openssl` can also be added to support SSL.

buildozer.spec:

```
requirements = python2, kivy, ffpyplayer, ffpyplayer_codecs, openssl
```